# Overnight, 3 Apps Stop Working

Tags: applications, motion, pixelmator

Woke up this morning, and 3 apps are not working.  Pixelmator, FCPX and Motion all are getting the same message, e.g., “Pixelmator” is damaged and can’t be opened. Delete “Pixelmator” and download it again from the App Store.

As a test, I tried deleting Pixelmator, and downloading it again, but I get the same message.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated, because I have a lot of editing to do!

Comment: Has there been any change in the date/time settings ?

Comment: No, I hadn't done anything, and the everything looks the same.

Comment: I also tried deleting Motion, and downloading it again, but I still get the same message.

Comment: As was suggested in another post, I also tried changing System Preferences/Security & Privacy to allow apps downloaded from anywhere.  I then did the delete and reinstall, but had the same message.

Comment: Also tried this from another post, but it didn't work:  In Terminal, run "xattr -rc /Volumes/Application.app", that should fix it (naturally, replace "/Volumes/Application.app" with your actual application path.

Comment: Problem solved! On phone with Apple Support, they had me do the System preferences fix I mentioned earlier, and then restart the computer.  The restart was the missing piece for me.

Comment: @Tom Feel free to write that as an answer!